# instantiating a pointer to function from an inherited class

Tags: c++

I am trying to study the details of this [Generic object-oriented differential equations integrators class](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/CUJ/2003/0311/0311roussel/cuj0311roussel.htm) but I have some problems to compile the simpler example. The idea is define  a main class of integrators  from which all the other integration-methods classes are derived via inheritance. Here is the code for the implementation of the Euler's method.

```
//file integrator.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>


template <class C /* a container */, class T> class Integrator{
protected:
C statevector;
T t, h;

// a pointer to the function to be integrated
void (*return_derivs)(const C& x, const T t, C& deriv);//OK, I understand that a pointer to ODEs system is neede.

Integrator (const C&, const T, const T,
        void (*)(const C&, const T, C&)); //Question: why use void(*) in place of void (*return_derivs)?

public:
virtual ~Integrator() { }
virtual void step(void) = 0;
virtual void set_step_size(T new_h) {h = new_h;}

T current_time(void) const {return(t);}
void get_state(C&, T&) const;
};


template <class C, class T, class B /* base type of C */>
class Euler : public Integrator<C,T>
{
private:
  C dxdt;

public:
  Euler (const C &x0, const T t0, const T h_init,
     void (*dxdt_calc)(const C&, const T, C&))
    : Integrator <C,T> (x0, t0, h_init, dxdt_calc),
      dxdt(x0) { }

  void step(void);
};

template <class C, class T, class B>
void Euler<C,T,B>::step(void) // I guess, the resolution of the Integrator class variables id needed. Consequently I modify this part of the code. 
{
  Integrator<C,T>::return_derivs(Integrator<C,T>::statevector,Integrator<C,T>::t,dxdt);
  Integrator<C,T>::statevector += B(Integrator<C,T>::h)*dxdt;
  Integrator<C,T>::t += Integrator<C,T>::h;
}
```

The main program in which the Euler integrator object is instantiated:

```
#include <complex>
#include <valarray>
#include "integrator.hpp"
using namespace std;

namespace discretization_data
{
  const complex<double> i(0,1);
  unsigned int nmesh = 10;
}

void discretized_odes(const valarray<complex<double> > &psi,
              const double t, valarray<complex<double> > &dpsidt)
{
  using namespace discretization_data;
  dpsidt[0] = i*(psi[1]-2.0*psi[0]);
  dpsidt[nmesh-1] = i*(psi[nmesh-2]-2.0*psi[nmesh-1]);
  for (int loop=1; loop<nmesh-1; loop++)
    dpsidt[loop] = i*(psi[loop+1] - 2.0*psi[loop]
              + psi[loop-1]);
}

int main()
{
  using namespace discretization_data;
  // Initial conditions
  valarray<complex<double> >
    psi(complex<double>(1.0/nmesh), nmesh);

  Euler<valarray<complex<double> >, double, complex<double> >
    dSchrodinger(psi, 0.0, 0.01, discretized_odes ); //I guess the problem is here.

  while (dSchrodinger.current_time() < 50)
    dSchrodinger.step();
  //Some output statements would be added to a real program...
}
```

The problem is that when I compile the example the compiller cannot find the reference to the integrator object. But I don't undertand where the problems are?

To compile I use the command:

```
g++ integrator.hpp main.cpp -o main.x -lm
```

Obtaining the error messaje:

```
/tmp/ccre01X7.o: In function `Euler<std::valarray<std::complex<double> >, double, std::complex<double> >::Euler(std::valarray<std::complex<double> > const&, double, double, void (*)(std::valarray<std::complex<double> > const&, double, std::valarray<std::complex<double> >&))':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5EulerISt8valarrayISt7complexIdEEdS2_EC2ERKS3_ddPFvS6_dRS3_E[_ZN5EulerISt8valarrayISt7complexIdEEdS2_EC5ERKS3_ddPFvS6_dRS3_E]+0x46): undefined reference to `Integrator<std::valarray<std::complex<double> >, double>::Integrator(std::valarray<std::complex<double> > const&, double, double, void (*)(std::valarray<std::complex<double> > const&, double, std::valarray<std::complex<double> >&))'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please present the [testcase](http://sscce.org) with which you have been debugging so far.

Comment: The *compiler* cannot find the reference? or the ***linker*** cannot find it. Post the **complete** error message you're receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you posted the complete code - there is no implementation for:

```
Integrator (const C&, const T, const T,
        void (*)(const C&, const T, C&)); //Question: why use void(*) in place of void (*return_derivs)?
```

in the .hpp file you have provided. Since the `Integrator` is a class template, you either have to:

1. Put the implementation in the header file (which will make the constructor inline)
2. Explicitly instantiate the `Integrator` class for some parameters, and implement the constructor for these specific arguments in the .cpp file.

I'm guessing that you want the first option.

As for the question posted in the comment above - not entirely sure what you're asking. It's a declaration of a constructor that takes a pointer to function returning void and accepting `const C&`, `const T&`, and `C&` as arguments. It seems that it would then be used to initialize return_derivs. How would you want to use a variable in a constructor that's supposed to set it?

Comment: I don't know exactly. I am following the  cited reference trying to make work the implementation of the Integrators class as suggested in the cited reference.

Answer (score 0):

Boy, that CUJ paper was a long time ago! tsuki is right, you're missing an implementation of the Integrator base class. CUJ stopped publishing a long time ago, but their code archives are still available on the Dr Dobb's web site if you want to see our full code: ftp://ftp.drdobbs.com/sourcecode/cuj/. Our article appeared in the Nov. 2003 issue. I have also put our code up on my research web site: http://people.uleth.ca/~roussel/data/.